# What is a regex pattern to allowing comma-seperated list of numbers?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Tests:

```
1              PASS
123,234        PASS 
123,435,       FAIL
1,             FAIL
124,dsds,33    FAIL
121,121,1212   PASS
```

So, you can have any amount of numbers.

Also, if it matters, i'm working in C#, and i plan to coerce a list of Int32's out of the values (after it passes the regex).

What regex pattern can i use for this?

Comment: what is the question ? do you ask for the regex ?

Comment: @dvhh - yes. Was that not clear?

Comment: @RPM1984 not very. note the lack of question marks in the question. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
^\d+(,\d+)*$
```

This will also allow leading zeroes, if that's not what you want you can use

```
^(0|[1-9]\d+)(,(0|[1-9]\d+)*$
```

Comment: @RPM1984: Don't forget to anchor the regex using `^` and `$`, depending on which function you use to match your strings.

Comment: @RPM: For example, `Regex.IsMatch("123,foo", "(\\d+,)*\\d+")` will return true, because the regex matches a partial string inside the subject. You can avoid this using the anchors for beginning and end of line, `^`, and `$`: `Regex.IsMatch("^123,foo$", "(\\d+,)*\\d+")` will return the correct result (false). Just mentioning this because it's a common pitfall and you don't seem to be very experienced with regex (:

Comment: Ahh got you now. And yep your spot on, despite programming for years, regex has never been a strongpoint. :)

Comment: Also ```^\d+(,\d+)*$``` would be slightly faster, because it avoids the decision in the last part of the string.

Comment: @JuanLopes It's regex, so presumably one does not care about the last nanosecond of performance :) But of course your justification is sound, this avoids one step of backtracking